# How I can stop form validation on the first error in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

How I can stop form validation on the first error in Symfony 2
For example I have mapping class for form:

```
/**
* @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\d+$/i", message="Non positive")
* @Assert\Max(limit="2147483647", message="Too big value")
*/
protected $myField
```

When I fill this field with wrong values I've got both errors
For example if I fill "-10" in form input and send it to server, I'll get two errors:

- Non positive
- Too big value

Does anybody know how I can stop validation after first fail?

P.S. I know that I can write my own validator (smth like `Chainvalidator`) but I am looking for symfony solution...

Comment: How can you get those two validation messages? One is validating that it is at maximum 2147483647 and the other is checking that it's not negative... I believe they're mutually exclusive?

Comment: Heh, @Jaitsu your notice let me to find out solution))
Symfony `Max` Validator has 2 messages:  
- `invalidMessage` - shows when value is not a number  
- `message` - shows when value is more then limit  
So my issue occurs when I typo symbols e.g. "sakdj" in input.
Sorry I've made a **mistake** in issue description(
And if I fill `invalidMessage` parameter with empty value (`""`)
All works fine for me...